# Route/redirect to default action by calling the controler in url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routedata

URL : localhost:4835/Login

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 'enter code here' }
}
```

i want to call index without mention a name of action.

Comment: Show you route definitions

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this in your `RouteConfig` file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Your Default Controller Name", action = "Default Action name(usually Index)", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can have your own mappings, just provided a sample here.